# Gradle Android project build

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I have the following script and when i try to run gradle from terminal i get the error
"Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'."

Here is the application 
    https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/DistanceDemo

```
 buildscript {
 repositories {
    mavenCentral()
 }
 dependencies {
     classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'
 }
}
apply plugin: 'android'

repositories {
   mavenCentral()
}

android {
 compileSdkVersion 19
 buildToolsVersion "19.0.0"

 defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 18
    targetSdkVersion 18
 }
}

dependencies {
  compile files('../EstimoteSDK/estimote-sdk-preview.jar', '../EstimoteSDK/guava-15.0.jar')
}
```

Comment: you have a old gradle version i guess. update it to the latest

Comment: its the latest one 1.10 and the build date is 2013-12-17 09:28:15 UTC

Comment: `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.6.+'` 0.7 is the latest

Comment: i have tried with `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.7.+'` but it does not worked.

Comment: you need the latest gradle version pls check for updates

Comment: http://tools.android.com/recent

Comment: The latest Gradle plugin for Android is 0.7.3 but all 0.7.* requires Gradle 1.9, not 1.10. We'll release a 1.10 compatible plugin shortly.

Answer (score 1):

The 0.6.* plugin requires Gradle 1.8
The 0.7.* plugin requires Gradle 1.9

Make sure you use the right version.

Answer (score 1):

This demo https://github.com/Estimote/Android-SDK/tree/master/Demos should be invoked with Gradle Wrapper. There is a script ./gradlew that should be used in order to use proper Gradle version.